# PHP SQL shows error while using simple array

Tags: php, mysql

The following SQL PHP query shows error, why ?

```
$plays = array("bionic","user54");
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE status='winning' AND agent IN (" . implode(",",  $plays) . ");";
```

Error

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE status='winning' AND agent IN (bionic,user54);. Unknown column 'bionic' in 'where clause'
```

it says `column 'bionic'` in error, but bionic is not a column, its just a username in column `agent`

Instead of array if I use `agent='bionic'` it will show results.

Comment: Literal strings needs to be wrapped with quotes, otherwise they will be treated as columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implode them with quotes around the individual values.  The shortest way I can think of is:

```php
$values = "'". implode("','", $plays)."'"

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE status='winning' AND agent IN (" . $values . ");";
```

Essentially you were generating sql like:

`IN ( bionic, user54 )`

Note the lack of quotation marks which means it's trying to use those names as column names.

You want to generate:

`IN ('bionic','user54')` for it to compare values.

But I will offer you a word of warning: You should always try to use an ORM or escape utilities to prevent `SQL injection`.

Comment: `escape utilities`? I think you meant `prepared statements` though.

Comment: Prepared statements are some of the methods.  But at the very least they should use escape methods to sanitize the query.  This code looks like beginner level programming so I didn't want to throw something too advanced at the OP

Comment: Escaping your strings is not the way to go though - [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: There are libraries to handle that all, frameworks as well, hence utilities. I just am warning them about the SQL Injection risk, not giving a full discourse on how to avoid it